# Какое самое длинное слово в сборниках законов?

Tags: лексика

Какое самое длинное слово в законодательстве Российской Федерации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Федеральном законе Российской Федерации от 12.06.2008 № 88-ФЗ "Технический регламент на молоко и молочную продукцию" употребляется слово, состоящее из 36 букв, «ультравысокотемпературнообработанное» (о молоке), которое и является самым длинным в законодательстве РФ.